# Connected to mongoDB via local node.js server. API can't PUT or GET on properly configured routes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Help me stackoverflow! I can't seem to use GET or PUT in postman (via my API) despite being connected to the database and having (apparently) correctly defined all parts of the configuration (they time out).

The request (via Postman):

```
GET http://localhost:3000/tasks
```

DE FACTS:

1. I am definitely connected to the database. The console logs 1 after logging the API success message.
2. All versions are compatible.
3. I've tried with 3 different online databases, had this issue with all of them, I'm definitely doing something wrong.

DA CODE:

Server file:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = require('./api/models/model'), //created model loading here
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<my username>:<mypassword>@groceriescluster-shard-00-00-vaffe.mongodb.net:27017,groceriescluster-shard-00-01-vaffe.mongodb.net:27017,groceriescluster-shard-00-02-vaffe.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=GroceriesCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route


app.listen(port);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)},
5000)
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';


var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};




exports.create_a_task = function(req, res) {
  var new_task = new Task(req.body);
  new_task.save(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};


exports.read_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findById(req.params.taskId, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
    console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};


exports.update_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};


exports.delete_a_task = function(req, res) {


  Task.remove({
    _id: req.params.taskId
  }, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'Task successfully deleted' });
  });
};
```

Model:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var TaskSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
  },
  Created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: [{
      type: String,
      enum: ['pending', 'ongoing', 'completed']
    }],
    default: ['pending']
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

Routes:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var todoList = require('../controllers/controller');
  // todoList Routes
  app.route('/tasks')
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);


  app.route('/tasks/:taskId')
    .get(todoList.read_a_task)
    .put(todoList.update_a_task)
    .delete(todoList.delete_a_task);
};

package.json

{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test env api",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \\\"No time for tests today\\\" && exit1\""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Here",
    "it",
    "goes!"
  ],
  "author": "Zack Haigh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "install": "^0.10.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
    "npm": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.34",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error when you try to connect? how are you trying to connect? We need some more details.

Comment: Only error is in the postman request. "Could not get any response". Not a very useful one but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puzzles me a lot:

```
var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route
```

As far as I know, in Express.js v.4 the way of insert the routes in the server is like this:

```
var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
app.use(routes); //register the routes
```

---

I would define the routes in this way so you don't have to use a function with app as param:

```
var express = require('express');
var todoList = require('../controllers/controller');

var router = express.Router();

  // todoList Routes
router.route('/tasks')
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);

router.route('/tasks/:taskId')
    .get(todoList.read_a_task)
    .put(todoList.update_a_task)
    .delete(todoList.delete_a_task);

module.exports = router;
```

And in server file use them like this:

```
var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
app.use(routes); //register the routes
```

---

Also in case you were trying to use `app.router`, it was left behind in Express.js v.3 and removed in its upgrading to v.4

Comment: Thanks buddy! Now I'm getting a 500 error and "TypeError: app.route is not a function" in node console. You've already helped a lot, but do you have an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you are messing up with the routes definition and how to use them inside your Express application.

Comment: First, let me say thank you for all the help so far. I've updated my code (can post if you don't believe what I'm about to say). I'm right back to square one! Local API calls still work (ie. `router.route('/')
.get(function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'woot woot!'})
});` , but as soon as I try to hit the remote mongodb server, I get the "Could not get any response".  I know my credentials are correct because I'm logged into the DB in mongo shell right now. Using the proper string formats for both! Tried with mlab and atlas.

Comment: Do I need to manually create a collection first? Every tutorial I've read has you writing to the DB straight from API POST

Comment: If you don't have data, you can't retrieve data!

Comment: I was missing the driver dependencies. I am an idiot and you all deserve free points

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your problem, but I can show you my configuration with `NodeJS` - `mongoose` and `express`.

**app.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { db } = require('./config.js')    
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise    
var app = express()

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${db.user}:${db.password}@ds135486.mlab.com:35486/${db.name}`, { useMongoClient: true })
    .then(function (info) {
        console.log("Conexion MongoDB mlab exitosa...")

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error MongoDB mlab", error)

    })
app.use('/', require('./routes/dbtest'))
/*...more code...*/
```

**models/Corpus.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var Corpus = new Schema({
    fecha: Date, //UTC time
    compressed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Corpus', Corpus);
```

**routes/dbtest.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Corpus = require('../models/Corpus.js')

router.get("/corpus", async function (req, res, next){
    try {
        var docs = await Corpus.find({}, 'fecha compressed').exec()
        docs = docs.map(d=> d.toObject()).sort((d1, d2)=> d1.fecha - d2.fecha)
        res.json(docs)

    } catch (e) { next(e) }
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Same issue with this approach. Connects to DB, can't do anything with the DB.